# swagger-springmvc IncompatibleClassChangeError on Tomcat startup

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, swagger

I'm trying to incorporate swagger-springmvc into my project. Before adding Swagger, there were no errors. Right now, maven builds successfully; the error only comes up when I try to run it on Tomcat (7.0.54).

```
nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

From researching online, the error is caused references to spring-asm in spring versions before 3.2.0. Steps I have tried:

- Exclude spring-asm dependencies
- Reorder dependencies in pom.xml

I'm using spring 3.2.8.RELEASE.

I found a property for spring-security-version set to 3.1.4.RELEASE, which depends on an outdated spring-asm, in my .m2/repository/.../camel-parent-2.13.2.pom.

```
<spring-security-version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
```

However, this property is never referenced anywhere and appears to be unused. There are also no spring-security jars in my dependency tree.

Error stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\vwang\Documents\workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\fxmobileGateway\WEB-INF\classes\com\trinet\fx\gateway\BackendConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:63)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 32 more
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.trinet</groupId>
<artifactId>fxmobileGateway</artifactId>
<name>fxmobileGateway</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.resourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <com.mangofactory-version>0.8.5</com.mangofactory-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.8.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.codehaus.castor-version>1.3.1</org.codehaus.castor-version>
    <org.codehaus.jackson-version>1.9.7</org.codehaus.jackson-version>
    <org.apache.commons-version>3.1</org.apache.commons-version>
    <commons-httpclient-version>3.1</commons-httpclient-version>
    <javax.validation-version>1.0.0.GA</javax.validation-version>
    <hibernate-validator-version>4.0.0.GA</hibernate-validator-version>
    <swagger-springmvc-version>0.8.5</swagger-springmvc-version>
    <camel.version>2.13.2</camel.version>
    <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
    <velocity.tools.version>2.0</velocity.tools.version>
    <oracle-jdbc-driver-version>11.2.0</oracle-jdbc-driver-version>
    <!-- <trinet.api.version>v1.0</trinet.api.version> <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format> 
        <buildtimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildtimestamp> -->

</properties>
<dependencies>  
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- swagger-springmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-springmvc-version}</version>
        <exclusions>

            <!-- Exclude Spring 3.2.7 -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- apache commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.commons-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-httpclient-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dom -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- castor xml utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.castor-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.castor-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- support for JSR 303 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.validation-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- oracle jdbc driver -->
    <!-- note: need to be installed in local repository -->
    <!-- see the command in etc/maven-install-ora-driver.txt for the command -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle-jdbc-driver-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- velocity dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>${velocity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${velocity.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- database related libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-security</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-xmpp</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>fxmobileGateway</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/integration/**/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/repository/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>src/main/webapp</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <!--
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <name>My Local Repository</name>
        <url>${user.home}/.m2/repository</url>
        <id>myrepository</id>
    </repository>
    -->

    <repository>
                    <id>ip-172-31-22-232</id>
                    <name>ip-172-31-22-232-releases</name>
                    <url>https://stash.trinet-devops.com/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
            </repository>
</repositories>
```

Maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.trinet:fxmobileGateway:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:jar:0.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-core_2.10:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-ext_2.10:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.scala-lang:scalap:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mangofactory.swagger:swagger-models:jar:0.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.10:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.10:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.camel:camel-xmpp:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.igniterealtime.smack:smack:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.igniterealtime.smack:smackx:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 39.955 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-10T13:15:54-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas / help would be appreciated.